# How can I solve the issue of 'failed to resolve import in '@/...'" vitest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite, vitest

This is the error I got. There is a problem with the file path I defined in the "vite.config.ts" file. Can you help me?

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la3lT.png)

Error Message:

```js
FAIL  tests/utils/ConvertFromDomainToCountryCode.test.ts [ tests/utils/ConvertFromDomainToCountryCode.test.ts ]
Error: Failed to resolve import "@/constant" from "src/assets/ts/_utils/ConvertFromDomainToCountryCode.ts". Does the file exist?
```

`ConvertFromDomainToCountryCode.test.ts` file

```js
import { describe, expect } from "vitest";
import { SetFlags } from "../../src/assets/ts/_utils/ConvertFromDomainToCountryCode.ts";

describe("Convert From Domain To CountryCode", () => {
  test("function defined", () => {
    expect(SetFlags).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Here it works fine when I make the file path "../../../constant/index".

`ConvertFromDomainToCountryCode.ts` file

```js
import { COUNTRY_INFO } from "@/constant";
```

Here i added "alias"

`vite.config.ts` file

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { resolve, dirname } from "node:path";
import vueJsx from "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  base: "/"
});
```

#### System

```
OS: macOS 13.2.1
CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
Memory: 91.50 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 16.18.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/yarn
npm: 8.19.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.18.1/bin/npm
Browsers:
Chrome: 111.0.5563.64
Safari: 16.3
npmPackages:
@vitejs/plugin-vue: ^3.1.2 => 3.2.0
@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx: ^3.0.0 => 3.0.0
@vitest/coverage-istanbul: ^0.29.3 => 0.29.3
vite: ^3.1.8 => 3.2.5
vitest: ^0.29.3 => 0.29.3
```

Just waiting for the path of the file to be found

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solve this error. I add this code in `vitest.config.ts` file.

```js
resolve: {
  alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: resolve(__dirname, "./src") }]
}
```

Comment: Here is the reference [link](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/3042#discussioncomment-5378497).

Comment: can not find ```resolve``` or ```__dirname```

Comment: @AmirRezvani `import {resolve} from 'node:path'`

Comment: yea, i figure it out later. @jonathan-dumaine

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and the answer helps to solve it but I wanna add you can import resolve from path

```
import { resolve } from 'path'
```

and if you haven't declared `@` in your `tsconfig` but you have dynamic path for some specific folders you can just specify them.

```
resolve: {
  alias: [{ 
    find: "@server", 
    replacement: resolve(__dirname, './src/server/') 
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an error when trying to use material icons with the default import provided by Material UI icons (v5) on my code that use material ui 4. The code I used was:

```js
import CheckCircleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle';
```

The error I received was:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "@mui/icons-material/CheckCircle" from "src/auth/components/Pricing/PricingTable.tsx". Does the file exist?
```

Since I am using Material UI version 4, I needed to modify the import to:

```js
import CheckCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle";
```

After making this change, the problem was resolved, and the component worked perfectly.